extends AudioWorkletProcessor class and using an existing audioNode inside the class
I would like to create a new AudioNode by extending using the AudioWorkletProcessor class but I would like to use an existing audioNode (let's say a GainNode) inside the class, for instance inside the process function. the problem is that I don't know how to access to the AudioContext inside the the Class or the GainNode.process function, is there a proper way to do so ?
I know how to create and connect audionodes the regular way, that's not my purpose here. I would like to create a new audioNode build from existing audionodes that could be used as one audionode entity.
TIA

Unfortunately there is no way to do this. Creating and controlling audio nodes  (like a GainNode or an AudioWorkletNode) that form an audio graph can only be done on the so called control thread. In practice that's the main thread so far. The process() function of an AudioWorkletProcessor conceptually is running inside of the audio graph. Changing the audio graph from inside is impossible.
